# System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-assembly

While trying to execute my web application, it throws the following error. 
It says Matrix.Data.dll could not load. I tried to rebuild the assembly and reference it again. But no use. 
Also, it is showing a warning 'Assembly binding logging is turned OFF' 
and what will be the performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging...?

Error in detail:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Matrix.Data, Version=5.0.3.16, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ed19106b2f44b5a8' or one of its dependencies. 
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

File name: 'Matrix.Data, Version=5.0.3.16, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=ed19106b2f44b5a8'
at Matrix.Administration._Administration.DoRequest(Boolean& plReplacePlaceholders)
at Matrix.AppServerHTTPHandler.doRequestDefault()
 in D:\FX\AppServer\Appserver.vb:line 443
at AppServer.AppServerHTTPHandler.doRequest(Kernel pKernel) 
in D:\FX\AppServer\Appserver.vb:line 373
at AppServer.AppServerHTTPHandler.processRequest(HttpContext context) 
in D:\FX\AppServer\Appserver.vb:line 107

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value
 [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated 
with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value 
[HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Comment: Download [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to the deployed location, open that assembly, and make sure it's not missing a dependency. If it's not then load some of its dependencies and see what they are missing.

Comment: Can it be that you  have mismatching .Net versions here?

Comment: @wonko79: I checked the .Net versions of referenced assemblies, they are same in V3.5 and created by using VS2008. One thing noted that they are 32bit assemblies tried to execute in IIS of 64bit OS....Is that a problem...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Accessibility.dll is most likely corrupted. You will not be able to delete the file, even as Administrator.

You must go into the security settings and change the owner from TrustedInstaller to a different user and give yourself permissions on the file. Once done, get an Accessibility.dll from a working computer and replace your corrupted version.

Best I can guess, an installer from Microsoft corrupted the DLL as no user has permission to edit/delete/replace files owned by TrustedInstaller.

Comment: Thanks @Ashok. I will check that.